# Changing/Updating a property within VB code

Tags: vb.net

I have this property PageIndex set in my class. I am setting up a button that adds value of int 1 to the property value when clicked but do not know how to set it up.

I have tried setting up event but do not know where to go from there

```
Public ReadOnly Property PageIndex() As Integer
    Get
        Dim index As Integer = 1
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("p")) Then
            index = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("p"))
        End If
        Return index
    End Get
End Property
```

And the button click handler

```
Protected Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: I have button called   Protected Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub

Comment: I added your empty handler. You can edit your question to add it next time, instead of pasting it in a comment

Comment: You are returning `Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("p"))`. Do you want to increment that value or return it? It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: so i have a pager set up in another class and that populates the the current page index, i am trying to set up a button that when clicked it will increase the page index by one instead

Comment: Where do you want to store this page index? You need to keep track of it. But since you are getting it from `Request.QueryString("p")` it seems to be stored elsewhere. Can you show more code so we can get a better idea of what you are doing? There's currently not enough information here to help, imo